# Trigonometric determinants

Tags: trigonometry

I've recently obtained my University entrance papers from 1967 (yes,52 years ago!) and I found the question below difficult. I presume the answer is a symmetric expression in the differences between alpha,beta and gamma.Am I missing some obvious trick? Any help would be appreciated.

Simplify and evaluate the determinant
[image]

and show that its value is independent of theta.

Comment: Row and column operations do not affect the determinant. Now with that in mind, do you recognize the Pythagorean identity?

Comment: yes I've done that,its the final answer that I can't show is independent of Theta.

Comment: Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since row and column operations don't affect the determinant, we may add the third column to the first column to obtain a first column of ones then by RREF obtain as first column $(1,0,0)$ and finally use Laplace expansion on the first column to obtain

$$\det(A)=\left(\sin(\theta+\beta)\cos(\theta+\beta)-\sin(\theta+\alpha)\cos(\theta+\alpha)\right)\left(\cos^2(\theta+\gamma)-\cos^2(\theta+\alpha)\right)+$$

$$-\left(\sin(\theta+\gamma)\cos(\theta+\gamma)-\sin(\theta+\alpha)\cos(\theta+\alpha)\right)\left(\cos^2(\theta+\beta)-\cos^2(\theta+\alpha)\right)$$

and by [Product-to-sum and sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

$$\sin(\theta+\beta)\cos(\theta+\beta)-\sin(\theta+\alpha)\cos(\theta+\alpha)=\frac12\sin(2\theta+2\beta)-\frac12\sin(2\theta+2\alpha)=$$
$$=-\sin(\alpha-\beta)\cos(2\theta+\alpha+\beta)$$

and

$$\cos^2(\theta+\gamma)-\cos^2(\theta+\alpha)=\sin(\alpha-\gamma)\sin(2\theta+\alpha+\gamma)$$

and similarly

$$\sin(\theta+\gamma)\cos(\theta+\gamma)-\sin(\theta+\alpha)\cos(\theta+\alpha)=-\sin(\alpha-\gamma)\cos(2\theta+\alpha+\gamma)$$

and

$$\cos^2(\theta+\beta)-\cos^2(\theta+\alpha)=\sin(\alpha-\beta)\sin(2\theta+\alpha+\beta)$$

therefore

$$\det(A)=\sin(\alpha-\beta)\sin(\alpha-\gamma)$$$$\left(\cos(2\theta+\alpha+\gamma)\sin(2\theta+\alpha+\beta)-\cos(2\theta+\alpha+\beta)\sin(2\theta+\alpha+\gamma)\right)$$

and since

$$\cos(2\theta+\alpha+\gamma)\sin(2\theta+\alpha+\beta)=\frac12\sin(4\theta+2\alpha+\beta +\gamma)-\frac12\sin(\gamma-\beta)$$

$$\cos(2\theta+\alpha+\beta)\sin(2\theta+\alpha+\gamma)=\frac12\sin(4\theta+2\alpha+\beta +\gamma)-\frac12\sin(\beta-\gamma)$$

finally we obtain

$$\det(A)=\sin(\alpha-\beta)\sin(\alpha-\gamma)\sin(\beta-\gamma)$$

Comment: Yes,I've done that,but I can't get the answer to show that the value is independent of theta,ie is a function of the differences between alpha,beta,gamma.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer

Comment: I enjoyed a lot with that! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

To make it a bit better readable, you may substitute

- $u = \theta + \alpha, v= \theta + \beta, w = \theta + \gamma$

So, the **first row** of your determinant looks like

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sin^2 u & \sin u \cos u & \cos^2 u
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, you may use

- $\cos^2 u - \sin^2 u = \cos 2u$ and
- $2 \sin u \cos u = \sin 2u$ and
- $\sin^2 u= \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2u)$

Applying this to the columns of the determinant you get (here only for the **first row**)

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2u) & \frac 12\sin 2u & \cos 2u
\end{pmatrix}$$

So, your determinant looks now like this

$$\left|
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2} & \frac 12\sin 2u & \cos 2u \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac 12\sin 2v & \cos 2v \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac 12\sin 2w & \cos 2w \\
\end{pmatrix}\right| = \frac 14 \left|
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & \sin 2u & \cos 2u \\
1 & \sin 2v & \cos 2v \\
1 & \sin 2w & \cos 2w \\
\end{pmatrix}\right|$$

Now, expand along the first column and use

- $\sin a\cos b- \cos a \sin b = \sin (a-b)$

$$\sin(2(v-w)) - \sin(2(u-w)) + \sin(2(u-v))$$

This also shows the independence from $\theta$.